# How to fix "Array arguments to MULTIPLY are of different size" error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This works for single cell output

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IFS(
      Kilowatts!F9<1,"",
      (Kilowatts!F9>=Tariff!$D$3)*(Kilowatts!F9<=Tariff!$E$3),Kilowatts!F9*Tariff!$B$3+Tariff!$C$3,
      (Kilowatts!F9>=Tariff!$D$4)*(Kilowatts!F9<=Tariff!$E$4),Tariff!$G$3+(Kilowatts!F9-Tariff!$E$3)*Tariff!$B$4+Tariff!$C$4,
      (Kilowatts!F9>=Tariff!$D$7)*(Kilowatts!F9<=Tariff!$E$7),Tariff!$G$6+(Kilowatts!F9-Tariff!$E$6)*Tariff!$B$7+Tariff!$C$7,
      (Kilowatts!F9>=Tariff!$D$8)*(Kilowatts!F9<=Tariff!$E$8),Tariff!$G$7+(Kilowatts!F9-Tariff!$E$7)*Tariff!$B$8+Tariff!$C$8,
      (Kilowatts!F9>=Tariff!$D$9)*(Kilowatts!F9<=Tariff!$E$9),Tariff!$G$8+(Kilowatts!F9-Tariff!$E$8)*Tariff!$B$9+Tariff!$C$9,
      Kilowatts!F9>Tariff!$E$9,Tariff!$G$9+(Kilowatts!F9-Tariff!$E$9)*Tariff!$B$10+Tariff!$C$10
  )
)
```

Changing F9 to f9:9 produces "Array arguments to MULTIPLY are of different size" error.

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IFS(
    Kilowatts!f9:9<1,"",
    (Kilowatts!f9:9>=Tariff!$D$3)*(Kilowatts!f9:9<=Tariff!$E$3),Kilowatts!f9:9*Tariff!$B$3+Tariff!$C$3,
    (Kilowatts!f9:9>=Tariff!$D$4)*(Kilowatts!f9:9<=Tariff!$E$4),Tariff!$G$3+(Kilowatts!f9:9-Tariff!$E$3)*Tariff!$B$4+Tariff!$C$4,
    (Kilowatts!f9:9>=Tariff!$D$7)*(Kilowatts!f9:9<=Tariff!$E$7),Tariff!$G$6+(Kilowatts!f9:9-Tariff!$E$6)*Tariff!$B$7+Tariff!$C$7,
    (Kilowatts!f9:9>=Tariff!$D$8)*(Kilowatts!f9:9<=Tariff!$E$8),Tariff!$G$7+(Kilowatts!f9:9-Tariff!$E$7)*Tariff!$B$8+Tariff!$C$8,
    (Kilowatts!f9:9>=Tariff!$D$9)*(Kilowatts!f9:9<=Tariff!$E$9),Tariff!$G$8+(Kilowatts!f9:9-Tariff!$E$8)*Tariff!$B$9+Tariff!$C$9,
    Kilowatts!f9:9>Tariff!$E$9,Tariff!$G$9+(Kilowatts!f9:9-Tariff!$E$9)*Tariff!$B$10+Tariff!$C$10
  )
)
```

Maybe trying to hard to see why ... and failing

EDIT

Here is the workbook I tested it on.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LCwtHxCanjcLgQZZkm2O3PafaYjZJUtMAR9MPALqCAA/edit?ts=5fcdfdcb#gid=0
[image]

EDIT 2

The problem seems to be caused by this in the Kilowatts sheet:

```
=ArrayFormula(('Electricity Meter readings'!C9:9>0)*(ROUND('Electricity Meter readings'!C9:9-'Electricity Meter readings'!B9:9)))
```

maybe the key to solving the problem

Comment: Can you please share a sample spreadsheet? It works with dummy data.

Comment: Usually means 1 of the arguments errors out producing `#N/A` or `#ERROR` instead of a array.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124685/186471

Comment: @Alessandro -- I added a link to the one that works, The only difference is monthly consumption is calculated in same sheet

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention it has to be public, or we won't be able to access.

Comment: @Alessandro. Done ... I am the one to be sorry!

Comment: Where is the formula you mention in your second EDIT located?  Your sample sheet has no Kilowatts tab...  And indicate in your question that the primary formula you want improved is in Analysis!D9, so people don't have to hunt for it.  But I just noticed that you did put a border around it...  Also, it isn't showing that error now.  Is it working?

Comment: @kirkg13 My first idea was that a comparison between ARRAYFORMULA with and without F9:9 ranges would expose the problem. The test workbook showed it was not that; it was the ARRAYFORMULA in the Kilowatts tab in the project workbook presumably getting things out of sync. I am working on that. Analysis tab just has data common to the very many project workbook tabs.

Comment: I'm still unclear where your issue is.  Your original question deals with a large formula, which you say gives you an error message, but it seems to be working, if it is the formula in Analysis!D9 - you haven't specified that.  Can you clarify exactly what the problem is, and what outcome you would like, and where that is in the sheet?

Comment: @kirkg13 My issue was ... what was the issue in the project workbook. Both project and workshop workbooks have Analysis sheets, so sorry for misleading you about that. The only difference was meter readings. So now I have to directly input those in the calculation sheet. I was trying to keep raw reading data input separate as done by separate party.

Comment: Hi Chris, it's not clear if the issue is solved or not. In your sheet there isn't any error, so I presume it is. If it is you should edit your question stating it explicitly.

Comment: @Alessandro - I need to restructure the sheet(s); when I have done that, will explain with screenshot by way of a further edit.

Answer (score 0):

If I was to [accommodate new entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328028/techniques-to-accommodate-new-entries-in-google-sheets), the only solution I could think of was to amalgamate the data/calcs into one sheet as below:[image]

This meant the meter reading input needs to be put directly into the calc sheet. With separate sheets, readings, consumption and charges could be easily compared. Relationships between consumption and charges differ because of the tariffs.

But I had to restructure the sheets to avoid their ArrayFormulas clashing.